# module 'Resources' and module 'Resources', declared in 'Resources.Designer.vb', conflict in namespace 'Resources'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Has anyone ever seen this error in Visual Basic 2010, if so... any idea on how I can resolve it?

The error is

```
module 'Resources' and module 'Resources', declared in 'Resources.Designer.vb', conflict in namespace 'Resources'
```

Comment: You have probably named something "Resources". Like a folder in which you have put a class, a module or an actual class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same - deleting duplicate file: Resources.Designer.vb in MyProject folder (which appeared to be here for unknown reason - probably some auto process within VS2010.

In my case I had two files (identically the same):

1. Resources.Designer.vb
2. Resources1.Designer.vb

Deleting one of them should do.